# How to make android studio (gradle) use Sun/Oracle Java?

Tags: gradle, android-studio, java

I have problem: my Linux development distribution excludes one Java version for other (OpenJDK vs Sun/Oracle Java). I would be happy with OpenJDK if not few Android studio (IntelliJ Idea) bugs that are incredible annoying: I cannot scroll with mouse on my second screen Android studio windows for example.

With Sun/Oracle Java IDE problems disappear, however gradle build fails by not being able to find OpenJDK (it searches  exactly in old OpenJDK Java path, which no longer exists). My Java environment variables are good (JAVA_PATH and JAVA_HOME).

How to switch JAVA version in gradle build? It seems that android supports Sun Java.
If I am wrong and android does not support it how to get isolated OpenJDK version for android only development on Android studio?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> org.gradle.java.home
> ```
>
> Specifies the java home for the Gradle build process. The value can be
>   set to either jdk or jre location, however, depending on what does
>   your build do, jdk is safer. Reasonable default is used if the setting
>   is unspecified.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html